# How to verify the gradient of a symbolic function using numerical gradient?

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods

I have a function $f$, which takes as inputs a three arrays and returns an array. 
I have written a symbolic function $g$ to calculate the gradient of this function and I want to verify that it computes it correctly. For this I would like to use numerical gradient.

Would I be right in doing this way?

- Calculate $f(x,a,b)$
- To calculate $x+\epsilon$ will it be right to add $\epsilon$ to every value of the matrix x. Then calculate $f(x+\epsilon,a,b), \ f(x, a+\epsilon, b), \ f(x,a,b+\epsilon)$
- Find: 
  \begin{align}
  & z_1 = (f(x+\epsilon,a,b)- f(x,a,b))/\epsilon, \\ 
  & z_2 = (f(x,a+\epsilon,b)- f(x,a,b))/\epsilon, \\ 
  & z_3 = (f(x,a,b+\epsilon)- f(x,a,b))/\epsilon.
  \end{align}

If each value of the matrices $z_1$, $z_2$, $z_3$ approximates (within some tolerance) to the gradient matrix computed computed by $g$, it is probably correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test you described is incomplete in the sense that you are only considering the directional derivatives of $f$ in the specific directions: adding the same number to all elements of $x$, etc. The full test would be

- Calculate $f(x,a,b)$
- Add $\epsilon$ to *one* entry of matrix $x$, and calculate the new value of $f$
- Take the difference of two values and divide it by $\epsilon$. Compare the result with the output of $g$
- Repeat for other entries of $x$
- Repeat for $a$ and $b$.